# Is there anyway to change the standard SQL SERVER reports? And/OR See the SQL Behind it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssrs

SQL SERVER (through Management Studio) offers quite a few standard reports, but I don't see how you could change the reports. I don't even see an option for extracting/obtaining the SQL Code behind it.

Is there any way to achieve this? Specifically, I am more interested in security reports (although it'd be nice to get code for all of them).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we can!

What you will need is a .NET decompiler such as [Telerik JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx). (Any other decompiler will do, probably, but this is what I use)

Once that (or another decompiler) is installed, all you need to do is locate the assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Reports.dll on your client (usually located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Extensions\Application).

Once you have found the assembly, you right click on it and choose "Open with JustDecompile".

[image: Open with JustDecompile]

Now, within JustDecompile, you can expand the tree view on the left until you see the "Resources" available, most of which are the "Standard Reports".

[image: List of reports]

Now, you can right click on any report and choose "Save".

[image: Save report]

You now have a copy of a standard report to inspect, copy, modify at your leisure.

Note: You can rename the report to .RDL so that Report Builder recognises it if you want, that's fine.

Comment: I have no idea what your background is, or how you came up with this solution, all i know is that it's impressive, unique and it actually did the job!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, run a Profiler trace while you run the report. It's just plain old T-SQL.

(Source: that's how I wrote the Performance Dashboard Reports chapter in the book SQL Server 2008 Internals and Troubleshooting.)

Comment: I actually had thought of this, but I was hoping for a simpler solution. This sounds to be more time-consuming than I had hoped. And I actually own SS 2012 Internals and Troubleshooting !!

Comment: Also, do you happen to know if that chapter still exists in the 2012 edition? I am not finding a *performance dashboard* set of reports (I see Nexus ones)

Comment: @LearnByReading, you can also create custom SSMS reports rather than changing standard reports. That allows you to provide a pretty rendering of your favorite DMV queries.

Comment: @DanGuzman this sounds silly but I clicked on "Custom" and it actually asks me for an RDL: so i think that function is there to let you create an RDL report yourself and give SQL server, I don't think what you suggested is going to work

Comment: @LearnByReading, yes, I was suggesting you create your custom RDL for your custom queries. This can be done with SSDT.

Comment: @DanGuzman well, this is what I'm trying to do. However, I was trying to use the STD reports as a starting point, rather than me creating something from scratch.

Comment: @LearnByReading no, I wasn't a coauthor on the 2012 one, and they didn't rerun that chapter. You'll want to create something from scratch though - just start with that T-SQL.